# Return sample row if result set is empty

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

What would be the most practical way to write a query, that returns single row in case of empty result set.

Something like (pseudosql)

```
(SELECT 1 AS c1, 2 AS c2 FROM ... WHERE ...) OR_ELSE(SELECT 0 AS c1, 0 AS c2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use either [generate_series](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html#FUNCTIONS-SRF-SERIES) function or [VALUES Lists](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-values.html) with a left join. The sample queries are below;

```
    CREATE TABLE my_table (a INT, b INT);
    INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (1,2), (2,2), (3,4);

    SELECT a, b FROM generate_series(1,1)
    LEFT JOIN my_table ON b = 5;

    |      a |      b |
    |--------|--------|
    | (null) | (null) |


    SELECT a, b FROM (values (1)) as one
    LEFT JOIN my_table ON b = 5;

    |      a |      b |
    |--------|--------|
    | (null) | (null) |


    SELECT a, b FROM generate_series(1,1)
    LEFT JOIN my_table ON b = 2;

    | a | b |
    |---|---|
    | 1 | 2 |
    | 2 | 2 |
```

Comment: You could also use `(VALUES (1)) AS one` instead of `generate_series(1,1)`. But why the `LIMIT 1`? I don't think we need it.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ You are right, I am improving the answer

Answer (score 0):

If some column is null you could use COALESCE():

```
SELECT COALESCE(C1, 0) as C1,
       COALESCE(C2, 0) AS C2,
       ...
FROM   YOUR_TABLE
WHERE  (Conditions);
```

If there isn't any row that match the conditions you could use a UNION plus a LIMIT. But you should add new column just to ensure rows are returned using the desired order.

```
SELECT C1, C2, ... 
FROM (
       SELECT COALESCE(C1, 1) as C1,
              COALESCE(C2, 2) AS C2,
              ...
       FROM   YOUR_TABLE
       WHERE  (Conditions)
       UNION ALL
       SELECT 0 AS C1,
              0 AS C2,
              ...
      ) T
LIMIT 1;
```

<kbd>*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=ffec419b287ccf23086ed8d204a47e60)*</kbd>

Comment: UNION + LIMIT + ORDER is what I had in mind, but I wonder if there's a better way... would it be possible to generalize it to plsql func?

Comment: Also the LIMIT 1 wouldn't be correct, as first query may need to return multiple rows.

Comment: But, if your query doesn't return any row that match the criteria, why do you need a row?

Comment: Default values - as it's part of much bigger query.

Comment: Could you add a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Well, it would miss the purpose of the question, as people would discuss the bigger query instead of the actual question that I have. Thanks for trying to help!

Answer (score 0):

Had to work around Excel's stupid bug where if a table is empty then you cannot do sums of columns because the table contains `null` and it thinks it is text...

In my case I had one column (`widget_id` in my example) that couldn't be null and I used that to distinguish the dummy row. But if you can't have a special value then you'll have to add a column.

```
with widgets_fixed as (
    select
        widget_id,
        widget_name,
        widget_price
    from widgets
union all
    select
        null as widget_id,
        null as widget_name,
        0 as widget_price
)
select * from widgets_fixed
where case 
    when (
        select count(*) 
        from widget_fixed 
        where widget_id is not null
    ) > 0 
        then (widget_id is not null) 
    else true
end
```

Answer (score -1):

This will return one row of nulls if mytable is empty and a normal table if it has rows:

```
SELECT mytable.* FROM (SELECT 1 AS one) AS dummy
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM myschema.mytable /*WHERE FALSE*/) AS mytable ON (true)
```

Comment: That’s the same as McNet’s answer, from 4 years ago.

Comment: It is different, you don't have to list columns you can use select * . I use it in c# project to get the list of query's columns.