# PostgreSQL return default row on empty result set

Tags: postgresql

For some reason couldn't find anything on the topic that would work for me:
[Return sample row if result set is empty](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/205796/return-sample-row-if-result-set-is-empty) and similar questions are using integers for joining.

I have a table with simple structure: **pk::int, key::varchar, value::varchar**

I need to do a search by **key** column and return the multiple **value**s. In case there is no matching rows (empty result set) I want to return a default value, e.g. the word "default".

Easy solution would be to have a CTE or subquery with **UNION** and **LIMIT 1**, but the query should be able to return multiple values (key column may contain duplicates), so this is not a solution.

I have come up with this, which is working:

```
SELECT value FROM mytable
  WHERE key = 'foobar'
UNION
SELECT 'default' AS value
  WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable WHERE key = 'foobar') <1
```

But the subquery is doubling the amount of queries on the data.

Is there a more elegant and performant solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a left join.

Assuming value cannot be null, then you could use coalesce to decide between the real value and the default

```
with t as (select 'default' value) 
select coalesce(mytable.value, t.value)  from t left join mytable on key='present';
```

But if value can be NULL, you would need something a bit fancier:

```
with t as (select 'default' value)
select 
   case when id is not null then mytable.value else t.value end 
from t left join mytable on key='null';
```

Or to be more obscure, you can make t be a table with 0 columns but one row:

```
with t as (select)
select 
   case when id is not null then mytable.value else 'default' end 
from t left join mytable on key='null';
```

> ... and performant solution

You haven't shown any performance issues in the first place.  So it is hard to evaluate if we have fixed them.

Comment: No, the value can't be NULL in my case, but this works really well. So the part I missed is to use coalesce the way you did. Thank you. Considering the performance - well this undoubtedly will be faster than my case as it doesn't execute the query on the table twice (I don't think optimization happens here).

Comment: The performance question here is more theoretical for now, as the usage of this query is during an insertion of records to the queue type table, about 100/s is the maximum estimated, but needs to be tested in real life scenarios